# AudioClip Issues when trying to play sounds on JFrame

Tags: java, audio, clip

I've been trying to play sound1 and sound2 using AudioClips. This is my code:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Sound {

private Clip clip;

public static final Sound sound1 = new Sound("src/Sounds/Classic_Horror_2.wav");
public static final Sound sound2 = new Sound("src/Sounds/Classic Horror 3.mp3");

public Sound (String fileName) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound.class.getResource(fileName));
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(ais);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void play() {
    try {
        if (clip != null) {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (clip) {
                        clip.stop();
                        clip.setFramePosition(0);
                        clip.start();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stop(){
    if(clip == null) return;
    clip.stop();
}

public void loop() {
    try {
        if (clip != null) {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (clip) {
                        clip.stop();
                        clip.setFramePosition(0);
                        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean isActive(){
    return clip.isActive();
}
}
```

When I try to do Sound.sound1.loop(); or Sound.sound1.play(); I get a null pointer exception. Same goes for sound2. Here are the exact errors messages:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(StandardMidiFileReader.java:207)
at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(MidiSystem.java:841)
at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:178)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1147)
at Sound.<init>(Sound.java:12)
at Sound.<clinit>(Sound.java:7)
at IntroductionComponent.<init>(IntroductionComponent.java:54)
at IntroductionGUI.main(IntroductionGUI.java:9)


java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(StandardMidiFileReader.java:207)
at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(MidiSystem.java:841)
at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:178)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1147)
at Sound.<init>(Sound.java:12)
at Sound.<clinit>(Sound.java:8)
at IntroductionComponent.<init>(IntroductionComponent.java:54)
at IntroductionGUI.main(IntroductionGUI.java:9)
```

I have repeatedly browsed stackoverflow to look for possible fixes, however it may be that fileName returns null constantly, or that my URL's are somehow incorrect. That said, for all I know it could be anything. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: You may want to accept the answers from some of your questions (if they solved your problems).

Comment: `src/` is key problem

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion of `src` in your paths...

```
public static final Sound sound1 = new Sound("src/Sounds/Classic_Horror_2.wav");
public static final Sound sound2 = new Sound("src/Sounds/Classic Horror 3.mp3");
```

is your key problem, `src` won't exist once the application is build and package, you should never refer to `src` ever.

You should probably be using something more like...

```
public static final Sound sound1 = new Sound("/Sounds/Classic_Horror_2.wav");
public static final Sound sound2 = new Sound("/Sounds/Classic Horror 3.mp3");

public Sound (String fileName) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource(fileName));
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(ais);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Personally, I'd make `Sound` require a `URL`...

```
public Sound (URL url) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(ais);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This way there's no confusion over what `String` means and you can pass a reference from embedded resources, file references or even from the net

Also from memory, `clip.start()` creates it's own thread, so there's no need to create your own

Comment: Thank you! I used to have it without src, and it still didn't work. Up to the point before you add the URL it still gives me the null pointers exceptions. Changing it to url is fine by me, I just don't know what url to type in unless I do file://Sounds............ Is that what you mean?

Comment: `getClass().getResource("/Sounds/Classic_Horror_2.wav")` will return a `URL` if it can find the resource, remember, this is case sensitive, so I'd check to path/name is correct, I'd also unzip the jar file and check that the resources as been included correctly

Comment: Indeed, passing the url as a parameter doesn't cause problems to my audio input when I use getClass().getResource(....). That said, the Sounds  folder is in my Java workspace, inside src, so I'm not sure if Java automatically understands that (and therefore my url is correct)... Also, forgive the noob questions, but where can I find said jar file?

Comment: What IDE are you using, most will include src in the class path when you run the program from within it

Comment: Eclipse will generate a jar via one of it export options

Comment: So, should I export my project and look for the jar file?

Comment: Personally, I would, it might give you a better idea of what's going on

Comment: Also, remember, Java Audio doesn't play MP3 (not many anyway)