# Sound with java does not play? Even 16 or 8 bits?

Tags: java, audio, file-io, wav

Hello my problem is that I cannot get my program to play sound, although I don't know what I am doing wrong, I followed the guidelines on several video and so far I have no clue how to do it. I even converted my files in .wav and 8 or 16 bit so I know that is not the file because java supports it.

Here is the code and the error message:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;

public class MusicPlayer implements Runnable {

    private ArrayList<String> musicFiles;
    private int currentSongIndex;

    public MusicPlayer(String...files){

        musicFiles = new ArrayList<String>();


        for(String file : files){

            musicFiles.add("./Music Player/src" + file + ".wav");




        }


    }

    private void playSound(String fileName){

        try{

            File soundFile = new File(fileName);
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            AudioFormat format = ais.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);

            Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(ais);
            FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);

            gainControl.setValue(-10);
            clip.start();

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();


        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//      ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2);
        MusicPlayer music = new MusicPlayer("Chillout");

        music.playSound("./Music Player/src/Chillout.wav");

    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        playSound(musicFiles.get(currentSongIndex));


    }

}
```

> Error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\Music Player\src\Chillout.wav (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at MusicPlayer.playSound(MusicPlayer.java:39)
    at MusicPlayer.main(MusicPlayer.java:65)
```

I don't get it, I tried with the file in scr and in the folder of the project, still file not found?

Thank you

Comment: Don't reference `src` in your code, it won't exist once the app is built/released.  Instead use `Class#getResource` to load embedded resources - also, don't treat embedded resources as "files", they're not, most of the APIs support either `URL` or `InputStream`

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951496/audioclip-issues-when-trying-to-play-sounds-on-jframe/35952204#35952204)

Comment: Your problem is just a folder issue. Put your path without space character and base of main directory. For example /home/emir/Music/myfile.wav

Comment: No it's not a problem of path, I tried the URL way and does not work, I tried inputStream and as well does not work. It seem that all tutorial out there about this are bad, as I get the same problem over and over again, also when it does not give me an error, absolutely no sounds plays!

Comment: _"I tried the URL way and does not work"_ what URL? Did you try something like `music.playSound("c:\test\Chillout.wav");`? (obviously make sure a folder called "test" with .wav file exists).... also regarding _"absolutely no sounds plays!"_ untested but I wonder if `gainControl.setValue(-10);` is reducing too much (you can't hear below zero volume)

Comment: No, it's not that, it was a problem that I solved just by changing folder address and instantiating an object music player into the the run method, this makes sense because you need to start the player through the constructor passing the string, the gainControl, has nothing to do with it because it's just something for later use. Thank you though I ll post the solution.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is an answer a lot of people are searching!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to quote my own comment above which gives a simple description on how I solved the problem. Now many people on the Internet are searching a solution for this, and most answers and videos are very disappointing as I searched for one hour for something decent and working.

If you are somebody searching for an easy solution for this problem, enjoy ;).

> It was a problem that I solved just by changing folder address and
>   instantiating an object music player into the the run method, this
>   makes sense because you need to start the player through the
>   constructor passing the string, the gainControl, has nothing to do
>   with it because it's just something for later use. Thank you though I
>   ll post the solution.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;

public class MusicPlayer implements Runnable {

    private ArrayList<String> musicFiles;

    public MusicPlayer(String...files){

        musicFiles = new ArrayList<String>();


        for(String file : files){

            musicFiles.add("C:"fullpath"/Music Player/src/" + file + ".wav");

        }


    }

    private void playSound(String fileName){

        try{

            File soundFile = new File(fileName);
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            AudioFormat format = ais.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);

            Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(ais);
            FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);

            gainControl.setValue(-10);
            clip.start();

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();



        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        MusicPlayer music = new MusicPlayer("Chillout");
        music.playSound("C:"fullpath"/Music/Chillout.wav");

    }


}
```